# Reading the nth word from a text file

Tags: java

```
try 
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(selectFile.getSelectedFile()));
    String str;

    ArrayList <String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    while((str = br.readLine()) != null){
        lines.add(str);
    } 
    String[] LinesArray = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);

    System.out.println(lines); //Prints Array list on the screen. 

    br.close();
} 
catch(IOException e) 
{
    System.out.println("The file cannot be read");
}
```

How can I print the n<sup>th</sup> number of word from the file?
For example, the user runs the program and selects a file with a paragraph and I want to print out the 12th and 30th word of the text file.

I have tried using split, but it did not work for me.
Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. paste only relevant code. 2.indent your code and format it properly.  3. post an example input file with expected result printed out

Comment: Since the file content can be converted to stringBuffer. StringBuffer has good api to retrive the nth string.  say subString(x,x+1)

Comment: @Zeus that's the nth character - not the nth string.

Comment: @alfasin yes thats true, i've over looked, so, user3009014 what do you mean by it did not work? You may have to use split with regular expression, with the following pattern. [\s.,]+ because the words may be separated with more than one space or more than one dot etc., I may need more explanation for this to rightly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("someText.txt"));
int count = 0;

while(input.hasNext() && count <= 30){
    count++;
    String word = input.next();

    if (count == 12){
        System.out.println(word);
    }
    if (count == 30){
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you already have the paragraph in an array, my suggestion is that maybe you can go through the array and keep counting the space, when the space-counter reaches the number you want (say 11 th) you start to print words meanwhile keep counting the space and stop printing after the 29th space.

Comment: How can I count the space? Sorry, I am a new to programming in general.

Comment: I agree with those comments above, you need to cut out some of the code in your question that is useless for people who want to help you.

Comment: for counting the space, just traverse the array, compare each of the elements to space using .equals(" "). and add 1 to counter if the .equals statement returns true.

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion. I think the code is clearer now. Thanks. I`ll try it and see if it works.